# Cocos2d-iphone: Change the color of the overlaping part of two sprites

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I need the user to be able to drag and drop several pictures(sprites). However, I do not want them to overlap with each other. I plan to add something in the 'onTouchEnded' method but do not know how to do it.

The preferred way is to only change the overlapping part of the two sprites to red-tinted. However, if this is not possible, we can also change the two sprites both to red-tinted.

I tried to use sprite.color = ccRED. but it changed the whole sprite to red color instead of a tinted one.

By the way, both the two sprites are in regular sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is you can check colliding of two sprite

```
if( CGRectIntersectsRect( [sprite1 boundingBox], [sprite2 boundingBox] ) ) {
   // Handle overlap
}
```

You This logic in your case :

Also i got it  from [This Link.](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/ccsprite-overlap-checking/)

> Yes, it should… though it might look a little weird, depending on how exactly your sprites are shaped. You can also try testing for distance, which works better if your sprites are more circular:

```
// This is how close the sprites have to be for the game to think that they're colliding
// (or overlapping). Use a smaller value than 0.5 if you want them to be closer together
// in order for there to be a collision.
float distanceForCollision = (sprite1.contentSize.width * 0.5) + (sprite2.contentSize.width * 0.5);

// This is how close the sprites actually are
float actualDistance = ccpDistance( sprite1.position, sprite2.position );

// Check if they're close enough
if( actualDistance <= distanceForCollision ) {
// Handle overlap
}
```

> Both methods work really well, but like I said… it might look a little strange, depending on the shape. Testing for collision/overlap with, say, star-shaped sprites would look a little weird using either method. Still, for menus and drag & drop, it should be enough.

Comment: First, thanks. I have tried to use CGRectIntersectsRect and it works for detecting collisions. But after that, I tried to use sprite.color = ccRED, and the whole picture turns red while my initial attention is just to make it reddish (like highlighting.) Is there any way to do this? I do not want to everytime change the picture of the sprite (to a reddish one) because i thought it may not be memory efficient. Thanks.